# Roll Two Dice Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Instructions: Simulate rolling 2 die with 6 sides each 100 times and count these 3 
cases

-The dice sum equals 7

-The 2 die are doubles (same number)

-The dice sum is 10,11, or 12 (greather than or equals to 10)

What I have:

```
from random import randint

def rolldie(): 
    return randint(1, 7) + randint(1, 7)

n=10 
for j in range(n): 
    print(str(j) + ". Outcome: " + str(rolldie()))`
```

Overall I don't know if this is correct. Looking for more help. Thank you.

Comment: Haha...Playing Craps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the values of both dice, not their sum, so you can compare whether they were each the same value.

```
def roll_dice():
    return (random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6))

equal_7 = 0
doubles = 0
ten_or_more = 0

for i in range(100):
    d1, d2 = roll_dice()
    if d1 + d2 == 7:
        equal_7 += 1
    if d1 == d2:
        doubles += 1
    if d1 + d2 >= 10:
        ten_or_more += 1
```